# Running C Program on Windows 8.1 using Python (or not Python)

Tags: python, c, windows

The original goal was to write a software executable on Windows platform that could read numbers from 7-segment displays and record it at a constant time interval. I tried out a couple of OCR libraries in Python (since I was planning to write the program in Python) but learned that they are more suitable for handwritten letters and soon redirected my attention to another open source program written in C, specifically designed for reading numbers from 7-segment displays: http://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~auerswal/ssocr/

So I compiled the source code in Linux and planned to move the compiled file, along with its linked library files, to the Windows machine, naively believing that I could simply "exec" from a Python script to execute the program. It turns out it couldn't - just trying to run the program (after manually adding an .exe extension at the end and double clicking) generates a response "the app cannot run on this pc. to find a version for this computer, check with the software publisher".

So my question is, whether there is a way to simply execute the C program from a script on Windows platform, and if not, what you might suggest me do to complete the aforementioned task?

Comment: There's a link to using the application on windows in the link in your question, you know?

Comment: Yes, using Cygwin. But I was curious whether there was a more straight-forward method.

Comment: Straightforward? How so?

Comment: Like I mentioned, is there a way to complete this by calling the file from a script and etc.?

Comment: Compile the code using cygwin, call it with [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html/) as needed?

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering why I would need Cygwin when I already have the code compiled from Linux. The response below makes it more clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute any program using Python (like other programming languages). But what happens (for all languages) is that they do a system call and ask the underlying operating system to execute the program, because that is one of the responsibilities of the OS.

Open a Python REPL (or write a Python script) and try this (This is only one of the ways to execute a program from python)

```
import subprocess
# if you're on windows call this
subprocess.call("notepad", shell=True)
# If on Linux call this
subprocess.call("ls", shell=True)
```

What happens is that Python asks OS to execute the specified program (notepad or ls), weather OS can run the requested application is another story.

Your C program is compiled on Linux so it is an executable in a format that Linux can run (probably ELF format). Windows requires executable files to be in a different file format. File extensions just help the environment to treat files appropriately. If you change the extension of your Linux executable to '.exe', it does not change its content, so Windows still would not be able to run it.

You need to recompile your C program on Windows so the compiled program is executable on Windows. If the program requires a POSIX environment (for example if it uses fork() syscalls or etc.), then you could use Cygwin on Windows (that provides system calls and libraries available in Linux for Windows) to compile it.

Comment: So the output from compiling on Cygwin will be different from the output from Linux?

Comment: Yes, it will be a different file, in Windows executable format. Please note you might not need Cygwin, maybe you could compile it with any other C compiler on Windows. But you'll need Cygwin if it is using libraries that are not available in Windows. You'll need to refer to documentation of the C program, or just try to compile it without Cygwin and see what happens.